# ADF Copy Activity Not copying all data

Tags: database, azure-data-factory, azure-sql-server

Here is my scenario.

I am using a simple copy activity in ADF to move data from one SQL Server to another.

I mainly do a full load to start off and then write a SQL Query to fetch data from last 3 hours. Followed by a trigger run each hour.

My data pipeline works like this:

Source -> Azure Table storage -> Azure SQL.
Problem is happening from source to Table.

It is working fine for all other tables except one.

For that particular table it is only copying 1 row. Unless I go back in and do a full load thats when I get all the data.

Can someone please help me understand what is going on.

Please ask for clarification and more details if needed.

Comment: So is about solving code problem. There is no code problem here. You may ask your question here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this issue because of following reason

•   **Primary key violation when writing to SQL Server/Azure SQL Database/Azure Cosmos DB.**

For example: Copy data from a SQL server to a SQL database. A primary key is defined in the sink SQL database, but no such primary key is defined in the source SQL server. The duplicated rows that exist in the source cannot be copied to the sink. Copy activity copies only the first row of the source data into the sink. The subsequent source rows that contain the duplicated primary key value are detected as incompatible and are skipped.

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-fault-tolerance#supported-scenarios

Comment: Apologies, I would like to amend my question. The data is being copied into Table storage, then from table to SQL. Problem occurs from source to table.(only one row is copied)